# SQL Server : Incorrect syntax near '<' and 'day' Expecting '(' or SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, case

Below is a procedure for returning a query to my darknet project. I want to get records for the last 6 months, last 1 week and last 1 month in where.

I will return the 'KAYITTARIHI' according to the query result

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CVSearch]
    @Adi nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @Soyadi nvarchar(50) = NULL,
    @BasvuruTarihi nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
    IF (@Adi = '')
        SET @Adi = NULL

    IF (@Soyadi = '')
        SET @Soyadi = NULL

    IF (@BasvuruTarihi = '')
        SET @BasvuruTarihi = NULL
            
    SELECT ID_CV 
    FROM CV 
    WHERE KULLANICILAR_CV_SILMEDURUMU  = 0 
      AND ADI LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Adi, ADI) + '%' 
      AND SOYADI LIKE '%' + ISNULL(@Soyadi, SOYADI) + '%' 
      AND CASE 
             WHEN @BasvuruTarihi = 'Hepsi' 
                THEN KAYITTARIHI  
             WHEN @BasvuruTarihi = 'Last 1 week' 
                THEN DATEDIFF(day, KAYITTARIHI, GETDATE()) < 8 
             WHEN @BasvuruTarihi = 'Last 1 month' 
                THEN DATEDIFF(day, KAYITTARIHI, GETDATE()) < 31  
             WHEN @BasvuruTarihi = 'Last 6 month' 
                THEN DATEDIFF(day, KAYITTARIHI, GETDATE()) < 180 
             ELSE @BasvuruTarihi 
          END = KAYITTARIHI
```

but I get these errors :

> Incorrect syntax near '<' =>>  when @BasvuruTarihi='Last 1 week' then DATEDIFF(day,KAYITTARIHI,GETDATE())<8
>
> Incorrect syntax near 'day' Expecting '(' or SELECT =>> when @BasvuruTarihi='Last 1 month' THEN DATEDIFF(day,KAYITTARIHI,GETDATE()) <31
>
> Incorrect syntax near '=' Expecting Conversation =>> end = KAYITTARIHI

Comment: Some good use of line breaks and white space would make that SQL far easier to read, and debug.

Comment: Also, what you're have hear is a catch all query, but syntax like `like  '%' + ISNULL(@Adi, ADI) + '%'` is going to be far from performant.

Comment: You've put datetime comparisons as then `THEN` part of a `case` expression - which is illegal. A `case` expression can only return a value. You've also, potentially (depending on what those compares should do, got completely different return values from different branches - which is also illegal.

Comment: What does `then DATEDIFF(day,KAYITTARIHI,GETDATE())<8` mean? If you want a true/false result you need an extra CASE or IIF statement.

Comment: A `CASE` **expression** returns a *scalar* value. Have a look at yours; you have 2 clauses return a scalar value, and then the other 3 return a boolean result, and then *compare* those values to `KAYITTARIHI` it doesn't make any sense. Again, some formatting would have demonstrated that problem to you very quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a completely blind guess, but I am guessing this is something along the lines of what you really want. This still isn't going to performant, due to the leading wild cards, however, I've at least made as much of this as I can SARGable. I also add `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` to give the data engine to *best* chance to use a query plan relevant to the query.

```sql
SELECT ID_CV
FROM dbo.CV
WHERE KULLANICILAR_CV_SILMEDURUMU = 0
  AND (ADI LIKE N'%' + @Adi + N'%' OR @Adi IS NULL)
  AND (SOYADI LIKE N'%' + @Soyadi + N'%' OR @Soyadi IS NULL)
  AND (@BasvuruTarihi = N'Hepsi'
   OR  (@BasvuruTarihi = N'Last 1 week' AND KAYITTARIHI >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,-7,GETDATE())))
   OR  (@BasvuruTarihi = N'Last 1 week' AND KAYITTARIHI >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,-30,GETDATE()))) --This isn't a month
   OR  (@BasvuruTarihi = N'Last 1 week' AND KAYITTARIHI >= CONVERT(date,DATEADD(DAY,-180,GETDATE())))) --This isn't 6 months
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```